# US MAP, States link to HTML, HTML loads in a DIV on the page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, cross-browser

Disclaimer: The site I am linking to only has functionality coded for Alaska and Alabama at the moment, so only click those, the others just don't work yet. My issue that I'm running into is that when clicking Alaska or Alabama or any other state, the jquery doesn't always return a result. I think it has something to do with browser compatibility, or jquery version but at this point I am running out of ideas and need your help.

The website is:

http://electrix.com/reps_find_map_mag.html

The only two states I have a result coded for are Alaska and Alabama, so try clicking on those, the others just don't work yet.

The map is raphael. The jquery plugin I'm using is:

http://newsignature.github.io/us-map/

My jquery that loads the map and then loads in the right DIV another html page is here:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#map').usmap({
 click: function(event, data) {
    var description = "No state info loaded for this state.";
    switch (data.name)
    {
                case 'AL':
            description = 'alabama';
            break;
        case 'AK':
            description = 'alaska';
            break;
        case 'AZ':
            description = 'arizona';
            break;
        case 'AR':
            description = 'arkansas';
            break;
        case 'CA':
            description = 'california';
            break;
        case 'CO':
            description = 'colorado';
            break;
        case 'CT':
            description = 'connecticut';
            break;
        case 'DE':
            description = 'delaware';
            break;
        case 'FL':
            description = 'florida';
            break;
        case 'GA':
            description = 'georgia';
            break;
        case 'HI':
            description = 'hawaii';
            break;
        case 'ID':
            description = 'idaho';
            break;
        case 'IL':
            description = 'illinois';
            break;
        case 'IN':
            description = 'indiana';
            break;
        case 'IA':
            description = 'iowa';
            break;
        case 'KS':
            description = 'kansas';
            break;
        case 'KY':
            description = 'kentucky';
            break;
        case 'LA':
            description = 'louisiana';
            break;
        case 'ME':
            description = 'maine';
            break;
        case 'MD':
            description = 'maryland';
            break;
        case 'MA':
            description = 'massachusetts';
            break;
        case 'MI':
            description = 'michigan';
            break;
        case 'MN':
            description = 'minnesota';
            break;
        case 'MS':
            description = 'mississippi';
            break;
        case 'MO':
            description = 'missouri';
            break;
        case 'MT':
            description = 'montana';
            break;
        case 'NE':
            description = 'nebraska';
            break;
        case 'NV':
            description = 'nevada';
            break;
        case 'NH':
            description = 'newhampshire';
            break;
        case 'NJ':
            description = 'newjersey';
            break;
        case 'NM':
            description = 'newmexico';
            break;
        case 'NY':
            description = 'newyork';
            break;
        case 'NC':
            description = 'northcarolina';
            break;
        case 'ND':
            description = 'northdakota';
            break;
        case 'OH':
            description = 'ohio';
            break;
        case 'OK':
            description = 'oklahoma';
            break;
        case 'OR':
            description = 'oregon';
            break;
        case 'PA':
            description = 'pennsylvania';
            break;
        case 'RI':
            description = 'rhodeisland';
            break;
        case 'SC':
            description = 'southcarolina';
            break;
        case 'SD':
            description = 'southdakota';
            break;
        case 'TN':
            description = 'tennessee';
            break;
        case 'TX':
            description = 'texas';
            break;
        case 'UT':
            description = 'utah';
            break;
        case 'VT':
            description = 'vermont';
            break;
        case 'VA':
            description = 'virginia';
            break;
        case 'WA':
            description = 'washington';
            break;
        case 'WV':
            description = 'westvirginia';
            break;
        case 'WI':
            description = 'wisconsin';
            break;
        case 'WY':
            description = 'wyoming';
            break;
        case 'DC':
            description = 'washingtondc';
            break;
        // etc
    }
    $('#clicked-state').load('http://electrix.com/usrep/' + description + '.html');
     $("body").css("background-color", "#333");
  } 
    });
  });  
</script>
```

I have given you the page and the jquery I am using, please let me know if you know the solution to why this code isn't working in all browsers, or if you have a better code to use to achieve this, I will be sooo thankful.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking the consoles of the non-working browsers for errors?

Comment: the browsers I'm told it doesn't work on, work for me, and don't have any bugs

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I'm seeing the only issue is that you don't have HTML pages correctly set up for all your states.  So when you run the .load() method at the end based on the description name, because that file isn't present, it can't load any contents into the #clicked-state, so it breaks silently.

The code itself is fine.  Just get all the other destination pages working and you should be good to go.

Comment: If you want to prove it to yourself, just add an alert statement on some of the other states in your switch condition.  Again, I believe the issue is the fact that you only have certain pages coded.  The usmap and click handler are fine.